# Image load with Accordion using react and Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an Accordion made with ui material in react and I need to load different images every time I open an Accordion tab, but the image is outside of Accordion, in another div

This is the current code:

```
export default function CustomizedExpansionPanels(
  items,
  id,
  expanded,
  setExpanded
) {
  const handleChange = panel => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };
  const { title, text, image } = items;

  return (
    <div>
      <ExpansionPanel
        expanded={expanded === `panel_${id}`}
        onChange={handleChange(`panel_${id}`)}
      >
        <ExpansionPanelSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls={`panel_${id}d-content`}
          id={`panel_${id}d-header`}
        >
          <Typography>{title}</Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <Grid container spacing={5}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={5}>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
              <Typography>{text}</Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
            <img
              src={image}
              alt=""
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But the image is being loaded **inside** the ExpansionPanel, giving a strange effect, it needs to be loaded **outside**, how do I do this?

Comment: Your <img> tag is located inside the <ExpansionPanel>.  Does it work the way you want if you move it outside of the <ExpansionPanel>?

Comment: @CarsonEsplin That way it shows all the open images and not only when I click to open Accordeon. It should only display the image corresponding to the Accordion tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add conditional code to render the image only when it is expanded.  If you move the `<img>` outside the `<ExpansionPanel>`, you can key off of the expanded property that you passed down and only render it if `expanded === true`.

```js
<ExpansionPanel>
  [...]
</ExpansionPanel>
{expanded &&
  <img />
}
```

I made a quick example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-image-with-accordion-dt3sh?file=/src/App.js) with the material-ui `Accordion`